# Bash Command Works on Mac OS but not on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

When I execute the following command on **Mac OS**:

```
echo $( mongo -u admin -p admin <<EOF
      show dbs )
```

It works Perfect. But When I run the same command on **Ubuntu 20.4 Minimal** it just stuck on: 
**>**

Is there something wrong I am doing? P.S. I am new to Ubuntu. In my mac terminal I have **$** symbol and in my Ubuntu, I have **#** symbol at the very beginning.

Comment: You aren't including a string `EOF` on a line on its own with no spaces before or after it, so the here document is not terminated.  MacOS uses Bash 3.x; Ubuntu uses Bash 4.x.

Comment: Note that the `echo $(…command…)` sequence is basically the same as simply running `…command…`.  The only difference is in the way spaces are handled in the output.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, can you correct my command, please? I got confused where to put EOF Thank you

Comment: This might be of help? https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't including a string `EOF` on a line on its own with no spaces before or after it, so the here document is not terminated. MacOS uses Bash 3.x; Ubuntu uses Bash 4.x.

You need:

```sh
echo $(mongo -u admin -p admin <<EOF
      show dbs
EOF
)
```